# How to scrape the job postings from https://apply.workable.com/caxton using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, text, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape job postings from this website: https://apply.workable.com/caxton and am using Selenium with Python for this exercise.

Here is the portion of the website's HTML where I face the problem:

[image]

I am trying to reach the `<li>` tags inside the `<main>` tag but get the
Unable to locate element

error when I try to find the `<main>` tag using `XPATH`, `TAG NAME`, `CLASS NAME` or `CSS SELECTOR`. Please see my code and the result below.

[image: Code]

[image: Output]

Things seem to be fine until `//div[@id = 'app']//div//div`, since printing `elem1` gives the webdriver element as the output (please see below).

[image: Code]

[image: Output]

Could you please suggest what code I can use to reach the `<main>` tag and ultimately the `<li>` tags contained therein?

Comment: The name <li> tag got replaced by a bullet somehow. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the `main`

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@role='main']")
```

[DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcM68.png)

If you are looking for the job opening cards, this may help:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@role='main']//a")
```

OR

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@role='main']//li[@data-ui = 'job-opening']")
```

**UPDATE TO SHOW THE COMPLETE CODE:**

To get only the `main` element:

```
driver.get("https://apply.workable.com/caxton")
main_ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@role='main']")))
print(main_ele)
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="34757b3f076c7ad292e832b683654e29", element="73ee8fcc-807d-4066-a884-46f172d859bb")>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that `main` does not contain any text to render and hence webelement is seen in output.

To get the job cards:

```
driver.get("https://apply.workable.com/caxton")
job_cards = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@role='main']//li[@data-ui = 'job-opening']")))
jobs = [job.text for job in job_cards]
print(jobs)
```

Output:

```
['Posted 4 days ago\nEmerging Markets Macro Portfolio Manager\nNew York, New York, United States', 'Posted 4 days ago\nEquity L/S Portfolio Manager\nNew York, New York, United States', 'Posted 4 days ago\nGlobal Macro Portfolio Manager\nNew York, New York, United States', 'Posted 4 days ago\nFixed Income RV Portfolio Manager\nNew York, New York, United States', 'Posted 4 days ago\nFixed Income RV Portfolio Manager\nLondon, England, United Kingdom', 'Posted 13 days ago\nESG Internship\nLondon, England, United Kingdom', 'Posted 26 days ago\nTreasury Operations Supervisor\nLondon, England, United Kingdom', 'Posted about 1 month ago\nCorporate Receptionist & Office Management Assistant\nLondon, England, United KingdomFull time', 'Posted about 2 months ago\nFund Accounting, Vice President\nLondon, England, United KingdomFull time', 'Posted 3 months ago\nFund Accounting, Associate\nNew York, New York, United StatesFull time']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here, there are about 10 job-cards in the page, and first, all the elements are located using `visibilit_of_all_elements_located` and then looped through each of them to extract the text and appended into  a list, which is output finally.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic elements you need to use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for visibility of all elements.

Use following `css selector` to identify the li element.

```
driver.get("https://apply.workable.com/caxton/")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[role='main']  li[data-ui='job-opening']")))
print("Total li elements on the page: " + str(len(elements)) )
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

output on my terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within the [website](https://apply.workable.com/caxton/) you can identify all the *Job Postings* texts using the following locator strategy:

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //li[@data-ui='job-opening']//ancestor::div[1]//h3
  ```

Hence, you can using *list comprehension* and your line of code will be:

```
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-ui='job-opening']//ancestor::div[1]//h3")])
```

---

Ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`* and you can use:

```
print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-ui='job-opening']//ancestor::div[1]//h3")))])
```

Console Output:

```
['Emerging Markets Macro Portfolio Manager', 'Equity L/S Portfolio Manager', 'Global Macro Portfolio Manager', 'Fixed Income RV Portfolio Manager', 'Fixed Income RV Portfolio Manager', 'ESG Internship', 'Treasury Operations Supervisor', 'Corporate Receptionist & Office Management Assistant', 'Fund Accounting, Vice President', 'Fund Accounting, Associate']
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```